# python and json: how to move columns into separate sub-column

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python array of objects that is a result of dataframe received from a database.
Let's say it looks like the following flat table:

```
data = [{"name": "Name1",
"phone": "555",
"firstYear": "2018",
"lastYear": "2020",
"index": "1"},
{...}]
```

How can I create a parent column for the last two columns thus getting something like the following:

```
data = [{"name": "Name1",
"phone": "555",
"years:" {"firstYear": "2018",
          "lastYear" : "2020"},
"index": "1"},
{...}
}]
```

Thanks!

I have tried to use pandas' dataframe "rename" method but didn't understand how to create another "level" isntead of just renaming the columns.
I was thinking about manipulating the json object itself like "find and replace" but it seems to be very ineeficient and error-prone

Comment: Do you *have* to use pandas? I wouldn't use pandas for this (and I use pandas for almost everything)

Comment: no, not at all, Paul. I think maybe just plain python manipulating the json object is fine, too!

Comment: Neither your input nor expected output are valid *Python* objects. They throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Also, be aware of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over your `list` of dictionaries and manipulate them as needed:

```
output = list()
for d in data:
    temp = dict()
    temp["years"] = dict()
    for key, value in d.items():
        if "year" not in key.lower():
            temp[key] = value
        else:
            temp["years"][key] = value
    output.append(temp)
```